# Function that increments success or failure counters based on command results

Tags: bash

Currently i need to streamline a script to reduce lines

```
Success="0"
Fail="0"
Var=$((+1))
red=`tput setaf 1`
green=`tput setaf 2`
reset=`tput sgr0`
Success-Fail(){if} {then $((Success+=Var))}

if sudo apt-get install ruby-dev; then $((Success+=Var))
else
   $((Fail+=Var))
fi
if sudo gem install rails; then $((Success+=Var))
else
    $((Fail+=Var))
fi
if sudo apt-get install ruby mine; then $((Success+=Var))
else
    $((Fail+=Var))
fi

echo "${green} "Success" $Success ${reset}"

sudo echo "${red} "Fail" $Fail ${reset}"
```

i need to create a function that gets rid of the if then else and creates it so i just use the function. which will reduce 3 lines for one program down to 1 line.

how should i go about doing this?

Comment: POSIX sh doesn't guarantee `-` to be valid inside a function name. Some shells will allow it, but it's better habit to use names that work everywhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: really? Which shells? I didn't know that ANY shells would accept a `-` in a function name.    (I'm not suggesting you are wrong, I'm just curious.  Any shells you wrote yourself don't count).

Comment: @cdarke, it's permitted in modern bash with POSIX function declaration syntax, and (at least some) older bash releases if you used ksh-style function declaration syntax.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  just tried on bash 3.2 and 4.4, and confirmed OK using POSIX syntax.  zsh 5.3 also worked. ksh 93u+ (either syntax) failed `invalid function name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SuccessFail() { if "$@"; then : $((++Success)); else : $((++Fail)); fi; }

SuccessFail sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
SuccessFail sudo apt-get install rails
SuccessFail sudo apt-get install ruby mine
```

Note that if you use `$(( ))`, then you need to do something with the result, as this operation is an *expansion*, so it tries to treat the result of the math operation as part of a command. The bash extension `(( ))` can be used if you want to do arithmetic operations for their side effects and disregard their result.

Comment: No need to assign the preincrement, `SuccessFail() { if "$@"; then ((Success++)); else ((Fail++)); fi; }` would do the same.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, I know, but you'll note that I'm using POSIX-permitted function names; being POSIX-compliant in other respects as well seemed like a good way to avoid objections ("your code is already bash-only because of X, so why do you care about Y?").

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, ...cut over to `: $(( ... ))` as a compromise -- less wordy than the assignment, but still POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, ...btw, the reason I'm using a preincrement rather than a postincrement is to avoid failures if the OP is running with `set -e`. Don't need the initial value of `0` to be returned and thus the operation to be considered a failure (though with `:` that's now no longer a concern).

Comment: `SuccessFail() { "$@"; : $(($? ? ++Fail : ++Success)); }` yet another option, shorter it's its only merit. Regarding `set -e`, if set the script won't be able to count failures, isn't it?

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano, in the answer as currently given, because the failures are within an `if`, they're considered "checked", so `set -e` won't cause an immediate exit and `ERR` traps won't fire. If we moved to the proposal above, where the command isn't explicitly checked and we rely on `$?`, then things get more interesting (the `errtrace` flag matters, f/e) in ways that I'd prefer not to think about. :)